# determiner phrase

Tags: determiners, terminology

> He is **a** child
>      He is **more than a** child
>      He is **just a** child 
>      He is **such a** child.

Sometime I see one or more words precede the determiner. they can be adverbs or other determiners. Can these be called something like "determiner phrase"?

Comment: [Determiner phrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner_phrase)

Comment: Note though that the Wikipedia link is about a very different kind of DP, one with no empirical motivation.

Answer (score 1):

Right from the [Wikipedia overview on determiners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners):

> Determiners that consist of phrases rather than single words might be
>   called ''determiner    phrases'', although this should probably be
>   avoided as the term is also used to refer to a noun phrase headed by a
>   determiner. An alternative term is
>   ''phrasal determiners.''

If you want more of an answer, provide more question detail. Please look for other resources online before posting a general question, as we can only provide general answers, of which there are many already available.